# Отдельный класс для запросов в БД?

Tags: symfony2, symfony3

Где и как создать отдельный класс для запросов БД на symfony 3.

Я пробовал сделать в папке EffBundle\Repository класс requestRepository с таким содержанием.

```
namespace EffBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;  

class requestRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    private $em;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    }

    function users()
    {
        $stmt = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
        $stmt->execute();
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return $users;
    }
}
```

> **Ошибка:** Undefined method 'getDoctrine'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

Если делать такое в контролере:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$stmt = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
$stmt->execute();
$users = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Все нормально работает.

Что я не так подключаю в классе или вовсе не так это все реализуется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри репозитория к менеджеру можно обращаться через `$this->getEntityManager()`

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, мне не понятно, используете ли вы ORM, или нет. Потому что, судя по коду, вы делаете прямые запросы к БД. В таком случае действительно нет разницы через какой класс делать такие запросы: вы сами можете придумать структуру таких классов и инжектить туда Объект соединения с БД.

Если использовать доктрину, то под каждую сущность создаётся класс-репозиторий, как и сделано в вопросе.

Но если вам очень хочется использовать классы-репозитории, но при этом не использовать остальную ORM (что странно), то смотрите ответ @Iaroslav Gashuk.